# Keycloak user migration plugin not invoking REST API endpoint

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-plugin, keycloak-user-federation

Keycloak version: 21 (kubernetes cluster)

keycloak-user-migration version: 1.0.0 https://github.com/daniel-frak/keycloak-user-migration

**Problem:**
I've created a user federation client using this plugin which of course is enabled. There is no authentication setup on the URL and it is accessible if I visit it via browser or Postman.

I can login if the user already exists in Keycloak but if the user does not exist then Keycloak or this plugin is not calling the configured REST API endpoint.

I've checked in the logs (Debug level) and I can see that there is an entry from Hibernate, checking if the user exists in Keycloak db. And after few other log entries, there is another entry from Hibernate which is an INSERT statement for `Event_Enttiy` with the error `user_not_found`.

Between these 2 entries, I don't see any useful information at all, basically just some other log entries from Hibernate.

Question is how do I check if this plug-in is working because I don't see any logs from it and secondly do you think I've missed something when setting up this REST based user federation client. I mean if I have to change the Authentication flow or the OAuth Client needs some specific settings and then this plugin will trigger.